# jQuery - if body contains exact string then make variable true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got on my page this two elements.

```
<p>Some text<p>
<p>Some text that I need</p>
```

If there is text with exact text "Some text that I need" then I want my variable **test** to be true. If not then must be false. So if page contains only Some text, need or that, then must be variable false.

My code doesnt work, why?

```
var test = $("body").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "Some text that I need" ? true : false;
})
```

Comment: "this" refers to the body tag.

Comment: $(this) in that context is the body tag...

Comment: The body is **never** going to contain `Some text that I need` becuase it contains `<p>Some text that I need</p>`. It is not clear how you want this to work?

Comment: if this refer to body then  $(this).text() will return whole html written inside the body which will never match with your text.

Comment: This text should once in p element, once in span sometimes in li element.

Comment: Sidenote: the ? true : false part is redundant, since `$(this).text() === "Some text that I need"` will already evaluate to true or false.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problem. First of all you should select the `p` elements using `$("p")`.

But `.filter` will always return a jQuery result set and if there is not match it will be an empty result set so you need to test if there is an element in the result set using `.length`.

```
var test = $("p").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() === "Some text that I need";
}).length > 0;
```

**EDIT** added `.trim` so that it will also match `<p> Some text that I need  </p>`

Based on your comment 
`This text should once in p element, once in span sometimes in li element.`:

You need to select all elements in the document:

```
var test = $("body *").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() === "Some text that I need";
}).length > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var test = $("body *").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "Some text that I need" ? true : false;
}).length > 0;
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pybd5m8/1/)

Comment: @dfsq The OP is asking when the body contains an element with specific text, he wants `test` to be true, right?

Comment: Right, but it still doesn't mean that this paragraphs are direct children of body. Anyway, maybe it will be useful for OP. Cheers! Btw, OP wants boolean result, length is a number, so probably `length > 0`.

Comment: @dfsq Okay, I updated my answer, it should work now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example to do this would be :

I am using `.each()` here

```
$("body *").each() //will handle any child containing the text you are looking for

$("body p").each() //will handle any p tag containing the text you are looking for

$("body p, body li").each() //will handle any p or li tag containing the text you are looking for
```

```js
var test = false;
var searchText = "Some text that I need";
$("body *").each(function() { //will handle any child containing the text you are looking for
  if ($(this).text().trim() === searchText) {
    test = true;
    return;
  }
});
console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text that I need</p>
<span>Some text that I need</span>
```